# Ajax loads randomly the full or partial content of remote page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am having this exact problem with my coding:

From `the_page.php` I load the content of `the_template.php` using Ajax.

The thing is that sometimes it shows correctly the full content of `the_template.php` and sometimes not. The strange thing is that when I click on the `response` through the "inspect element" I see that everytime the full content was loaded, but partially shown on the actual page.

If I hit refresh, sometimes it is fully loaded, but sometimes not.

Does anyone have any clue about what may go wrong?

**the_page.php**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "url here",
    cache: false,
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(data) {
        $('#currTabTarget').html(data);
    }
});
```

**the_template.php**

```
html and js code
```

**response on inspect element**

```
It loads the full code everytime, as it should be
```

Comment: is this wordpress? if so, consider adding teh wordpress tag

Comment: @Orangesandlemons no wordpress, just simple code from scratch

Comment: have you tried it without `dataType: "html",`

Comment: @codenut yes, no difference at all